# Can I remote debug a C++ makefile project from a windows vm using Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile

I am on a Windows VM which has eclipse installed.
I connect to a remote centos machine using putty (yes command line)
I work on a large C++ makefile project there.
I have learnt to use gdb within putty and everything is ok.

Is there any way I can use Eclipse present in my Windows to debug the C++ makefile project present in my remote CentOS machine ?

I have the following installed on my windows VM

- Winscp
- Putty
- Eclipse

I wont be able to install anything else.

I also wont be able to install anything else into my centos machine unless I can justify the reason.

**I believe this is NOT an exact duplicate.**
I searched high and low for a solution to this, most answers seem to be for a different application or requires some additional installations or maybe the instructions are not clear.

Please provide me a step to step guide as I am new to Eclipse, and 2yrs old into linux.

Basically a windows programmer, I have seen a VS solution to remote debugging, but I wont be able to install VS into my remote machine so thats out of question.

So the above ... or ... any GUI (Visual Studio kind) type solution that would make the remote command line GDB ... a breeze.

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide you with a step-by-step solution because I (a) don't use Windows and (b) don't use Eclipse.  However, I will tell you that there IS a remote debugging solution for GDB: there's a small program called gdbserver which runs on the host where the program to be debugged runs, then a GDB process (which must have access to the on-disk program being debugged) runs on your desktop and can connect to the gdbserver process on the remote host, and that gdbserver connects to the program to be debugged and passes information back and forth.

Comment: I've used this many times on all sorts of situations including cross-compiled systems.  It can be tricky: for example you need a "cross debugger" GDB, which runs on your desktop (Windows) but is built to debug the remote system (GNU/Linux).  Once you get it set up, though, it's pretty seamless.

Comment: Another option is to run Eclipse in a GNU/Linux virtual machine on your Windows desktop, then everything will match up and GDB and gdbserver will be the same.  Or maybe WSL would work, I don't know much about it.  Sorry I can't give details, but good luck!

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks for the response. Sure will try that. _(I hope gdbserver is running on my remote linux machine)_  Just to be clear, I am looking for a GUI based solution that I can work more with a mouse (Visual studio, eclipse kind of experience.) Edited my post

Comment: I understand, but Eclipse (from what I know) just presents a GUI front-end to GDB.  If you can get the gdbserver etc. running then you can use Eclipse to drive it just like you would when debugging a local program.